# Getting reference to internal telephony Connection instance

Tags: android, telephony, internal

Can I get a reference to the `com.android.internal.telephony.Connection` instance of an incoming call? Can it be done before the call has been accepted?

If not, can I get information of an incoming call other then the phone number?

Answer (score 0):

create aidl file to get reference to the com.android.internal.telephony.Connection. See this link---------http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html

Comment: Thanks Santanu, but I am not just looking for a way to accept a call. I want to get the com.android.internal.telephony.Connection object of the ringing call.